# Fail with ATI graphics disabled

Tags: drivers, 14.04, radeon, intel, fglrx

I've encountered following issue.

My laptop has dual graphics - Intel HD3000 / ATI radeon HD 6490M.
Before I have Ubuntu 13.10 and everything was ok. When I installed 14.04 things looks like this :`apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdccle`, when I have ATI enabled `fglrxinfo` output is correct. Problem is when ATI is disabled - output of `fglrxinfo` is following:

`libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/fglrx/dri/i965_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/fglrx/dri/i965_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3`

Despite this error everything works but I'm wondering if there is some way to disable this error.

Comment: There is no error here AFAIK. `fglrx` is the driver for ATI Radeon graphics cards. Now when you have disabled the card `fglrxinfo` shows you that it is disabled and instead you are using the intel graphic card. That is all.